# Is there a way to un-localize Plants vs Zombies on iPod/iPhone?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies, ios

My iPod Touch is set to French, and Plants vs Zombies picked that up and presents the game in French. The translation is just awful. Is there a way to un-localize it so it's in English, is it locked like this, or did I download the wrong version?

Comment: "The translation is just awful". The English in the game is pretty bad, especially since the zombies and Crazy Dave are basically the only ones who speak. Are you sure the translation isn't just reflecting that?

Comment: @DJClayworth I know what you mean. And no, it's more than that. It's a regional/cultural thing. It's like the game had changed from "bad general English" to "bad *Cockney* English".

Comment: @DJClayworth Another example: France (like most French speaking places) has an AZERTY keyboard layout, but Quebec has an adapted QWERTY layout. Very different. There's no keyboard in the game, I'm just saying this to illustrate the nature of the regional differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of is to [set your iPod to English](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2371).

I just tested this. Even though the App Store only displays the localized (in my case german: 'Pflanzen gegen Zombies') version to me, the game itself is in English as long as the system language is set to English.

After you changed your system language, the game's language should've changed as well. There is no need to redownload/reinstall the game.

Comment: Half of a victory, I need to keep the rest of the iPod in French...

Comment: Then I guess vous etes vissé.